# How can I get only the first matching record in a mongoDb join using lookup?

Tags: mongodb

Imagine two mongo collections.

FirstCollection is formatted like this:

```
{
    "JoinField": "this is my data"
}
```

SecondCollection is formatted like this (the real data is more complex and needs flattening):

```
{
    "FirstField" : "food",
    "SecondField": "bar",
    "Properties" : {
        "JoinField": "this is my data"
    }
}
```

SecondCollection contains duplicates and I'm trying to join the two tables and flatten the data into one projection.

This query will broadly do what I want:

```
db.getCollection('FirstCollection').aggregate([ 
{
    "$lookup": {
        from: 'SecondCollection',
        localField: 'JoinField',
        foreignField: 'Properties.JoinField',
        as: 'secondCollection'
    }
},
{ 
    "$unwind": "$secondCollection"
},
{
    "$project": {
        "JoinField" : 1,
        firstField : "$secondCollection.FirstField",
        secondField : "$secondCollection.SecondField",
    }
}
])
```

The only problem is that this contains duplicates in itself because it repeats the data for each duplicate in SecondCollection that matches a line in FirstCollection.

How can I only get the first record (or any single copy of the record) from SecondCollection?

EDIT: Apologies for lack of clarity. What I will currently get from that query, presuming a duplicate in SecondCollection, is this:

```
{
    "JoinField": "this is my data".
    "FirstField" : "food",
    "SecondField": "bar"
}

{
    "JoinField": "this is my data".
    "FirstField" : "food",
    "SecondField": "bar"
}
```

What I want is this:

```
{
    "JoinField": "this is my data".
    "FirstField" : "food",
    "SecondField": "bar"
}
```

Comment: Happy learning @Bob

Comment: Is this your req https://mongoplayground.net/p/77QM5yCW_rJ to understand more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [lookup with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) from MongoDB v3.6,

- `let` to pass local field to second collection pipeline,
- `pipeline` to match field and, set limit to return single document

```
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "SecondCollection",
      let: { "jfield": "$JoinField" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$Properties.JoinField", "$$jfield"] } } },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ],
      as: "secondCollection"
    }
  },
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q-z_iEVzS9v)

---

Second option from MongoDB v3.2, put a `$set` stage after `$lookup` and before `$unwind`,

- `$arrayElemAt` return element from specific position

```
  {
    $set: {
      secondCollection: { $arrayElemAt: ["$secondCollection", 0] }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z5k7nLhjAm6)

Comment: I think I misunderstood the ques :O

Comment: perhaps me o.O, not sure lets see.

Comment: @Gibbs Thanks - apologies for lack of clarity, I have updated the question. Just testing your suggestions now

Comment: @BobTway no problem, you mean the entire document is duplicate. Both of our(vishal, mine) solution would work I guess.

Comment: Both do work, thank you, accepted this answer as the syntax is just easier. Out of interest, the $set option is extremely slow compared to the others.

Comment: Notably, pipelines within `$lookup` seem limited in terms of being able to sort by time before calling `{ $limit: 1}` within the pipeline. So which one you receive (e.g. if needing to grab latest, if time-based) seems to be kind of a mixed bag?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you could [try this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pBgxsEqtkvQ)

```
db.b.aggregate([ //Used second collection as the source
  {
    "$group": { //Removing duplicates in the join field
      "_id": "$properties.joinField",
      FirstField: {
        "$addToSet": "$FirstField"
      },
      SecondField: {
        "$addToSet": "$SecondField"
      },
      "JoinField": {
        $first: "$Properties.JoinField"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "a",
      localField: "JoinField",
      foreignField: "JoinField",
      as: "FirstCollection"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$FirstCollection"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "JoinField": 1,
      firstField: "$FirstField",
      secondField: "$SecondField",
      
    }
  }
])
```